# React API call works only in inspector

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I'm trying to build a simple random quote generator.
When clicking the button, an api call should happen and the fetched result should be stored in the state with this.setState.

However, this only works when the inspector is open. When it is closed, the quote does not update: the last quote fetched while inspector was open keeps being re-rendered. No errors in the console (which I figured it's because it's all working when it's opened).

I tried different ways of doing this, including breaking the whole thing down into smaller components or doing everything in app.js (rendering JSX instead of other components).

At the moment, this is a summary of my code:

In app.js

````
componentDidMount() {
 this.getQuote();
}

getQuote = () => {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });

axios.get(```url```)
.then(result => {
  setTimeout(this.setState({
    quote: result.data[0].content
    isLoading: false
  }), 800)})
.catch(error => this.setState({
  hasError: true,
  isLoading: false
 }))
}
render(){
  let { quote } = this.state;
  return(
   <Quote quote={quote}/>
   <Button onClick={this.getQuote} />
)}
````

Expected behaviour: new quote is displayed at each button click with inspector closed.

Actual result: new quote is displayed at each button click only if inspector is open.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have been stucked on this for almost 2 weeks now, trying to figure it out on my own watching dozens of youtube videos and reading a pile of articles with no success :(

Thanks in advance!

Edit: FIXED!
I think there is a problem with the API. As soon as I tried with another one everything worked perfectly!

Comment: why the frick is your request out of lifecycle methods. put it back in the scope of componentDidMount where it belongs

Comment: Yeah I did tried that before changing it to this and it still had the same behaviour. I'm still exploring React playing around with the code to see what it does :) That's why it's not in the method at the moment. Regardless though, putting it in the method still doesn't render another quote when inspector is closed. What I haven't understood yet is: if I put the API call right in componentDidMount, can I do:

         <Button onClick={this.componentDidMount} />

in render? Is this good practice?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: May be if you put your example on a codesandbox service or any other like that, I can help

Comment: Try using  this.setState(()=>({isLoading:true})); And also this.setState(()=>{
  return{
     quote: result.data[0].content,
         isLoading: false
  }
}) .You're calling setState in the non-callback version multiple times in the same function call, which might cause problems.

Comment: Here is the codesandbox link:  [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-brook-1oxz4?fontsize=14)
I've commented out a few parts of the original code for simplicity. Hope the link works!

Comment: @sheff2k1 I tried your suggestion but it's not working :(

Comment: I played around with it a bit, and i don't see the problem. Each button press fetches some data from an API, but it's the same data each time. Nothing should change. Can you explain the problem again?

Comment: @sheff2k1 The problem is that it works only when DevTools is open, but as soon as I close it the functionality is gone. When I click the button again, it just displays the quote that was last fetched whilst DevTools was open, rather getting another quote. It's probably something I haven't understood yet, but it's difficult to test because I would need the console, which means opening DevTools, but then when I do everything works again :(

Comment: I don't see any way in the world, that the dev-tools can somehow affect the functionality of your program. What i do see in your sandbox, is that everything seems to be working as it should...I don't understand how it can get "another" qoute, if you hard-code the same exact URL(unless the backend is supposed to return a random quote or something like it).  If you want, you can share your FULL code on github or something, and i will run locally and see what happens..Btw: why do you need the setTimeout?

Comment: Just to demonstrate that everything seems to work, i've edited the sandbox to fetch some random data from a dummy api, every time u press the button :https://codesandbox.io/s/new-lake-xkbgf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193956/discussion-between-sheff2k1-and-erika-ravazzolo).